# Progress OpenEdge Browse Not Updating ON Leave

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

Here's the situation - There's a static browse that has an on GO trigger that pulls up a frame that allows for editing of fields relevant to said browse. When leaving that frame to return to the browse the records in the browse don't reflect the changes. I'm assuming that you need to either open the query connected to the browse or use the refresh attribute to update the browse in a on leave of the frame that allows editing. Thoughts?

Comment: You shuld try to post some code. Make a minimal example that shows the behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try {&open-query-{&browse-name}} (just as I wrote here, without a period at the end) after the editing to reopen the query. Or {&browse-name}: refresh ().